# How to have a Duplex stream wait untill finish event to start sending data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I've been trying to create a Duplex Stream that receives a number of objects, reorganize them and then pipe them to whatever stream is reading from my stream. The painpoint is that the reading part should only begin after all objects have been received (in other words, after the finish event).

How can I do that?

My current idea is that I'd have two different streams (instead of a Duplex), and that I'd simply make it clear on my API that the Readable stream shouldn't be used before the Writable stream tells you to do so - but that seems so wrong!

So, please, is there a better way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!
Seems like you can tell the consumer stream to wait by simply not calling `this.push()` until you're ready to respond.
All I had to do was to set a flag to let the duplex stream know the consumer is waiting for data, and then use the `on('end')` event on the source to check this flag and call `this._read` if the flag was true. Code is as follows:

```
constructor(source, options){
  super(options);

  this._isReady = false;
  source.on('end' () => {
    this._isReady = true;
    if(this._isOnHold) this._read();
  })
}

_read(){
  if(!this._isReady) {
    this._isOnHold = true;
  }

  // regular push sub-routine 
}
```

Of course, this would all be inside a Duplex Stream subclass.